# Trying to Show the products in Index.php connecting the bd

Tags: php, database, magento, magento2

Im trying to show my produts in index.php, but when i try to reload the browser this error show up:
**Exception #0 (ReflectionException):
Class "Vendor\Module\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor" does not exist**

This is my index.php Code:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index; 
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;


class Index  extends Action
{
    public $pageFactory;
    public $dbConnection;


    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $pageFactory,  DbConnection $dbConnection)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->dbConnection = $dbConnection; 

    }

    public function execute()
    {
        //Fazer a connection à base de dados
        $connection = $this->dbConnection->getConnection();

        //Fazer fetch de todos os dados da db
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM magento2_produtos';
        $result = $connection->fetchAll($query);

        //Exibir os Dados na bd

        echo '<h1> Dados da Tabela </h1>';
        if(!empty($result)){
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach ($result as $row){
                echo '<li> ID:' . $row['id'] . 'title:' . $row['title'] . 'Done' . $row['done'] . 'created_at' . $row['created_at'] . 'updated_at' .$row['updated_at'] . '</li>' ;
                
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }else{
                echo '<h3> Dados nao foram encontrados </h3>'; 
        }
        

    }
}
```

This is my DbConnection.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;

class DbConnection
{
    public $connection;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $objectManager = ObjectManager::getInstance();
        
        //ResourceConnection para obter a base de dados
        $resource = $objectManager->get(ResourceConnection::class);
        $this->connection = $resource->getConnection();
    }

    public function getConnection()
    {
        return $this->connection;
    }
}
```

My directory file: Vendor/Module/Controller/Index/Index.php

My directory file: Vendor/Module/Controller/Index/dbController.php

Comment: I know that magento generates a lot of files for code execution. Clearing these might resolve your issue. Then delete the contents in the var/generation (or generated/code for Magento 2.2 and later), var/cache, var/page_cache, and var/view_preprocessed directories. And after clearing, try accessing your page again. Magento will regenerate these files.

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace of the exception.